# Gitlab CI Runner | Custom mysql conf

Tags: mysql, docker, gitlab-ci, my.cnf, runner

I'm trying to set my own mysql conf for Gitlab CI Runner.
I found in the documentation how to set my own php.ini :

```
before_script:
- cp ci/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/test.ini
```

I didn't find informations about how setting my.cnf, I tried :

```
before_script:
- cp ci/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
```

But /usr/local/etc/mysql/ doesn't exist in the generated environment.

This is all my gitlab.ci :

```
services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  # Configure mysql environment variables
  WITH_XDEBUG: "1"
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony

cache:
  paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
# Install dependencies
- bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null
- cp ci/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/test.ini
- cp ci/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
- mv app/config/parameters.gitlab.yml app/config/parameters.yml
- mv app/config/config_test.gitlab.yml app/config/config_test.yml
- composer clear-cache
- composer install
- php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
- php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load

test:
  image: php:7.0
  stage: test
  script:
  - echo "Running PHPUnit Tests"
  - vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml.dist --colors --debug --coverage-text
```

And my docker_install.sh :

```
  #!/bin/bash

  # We need to install dependencies only for Docker
  [[ ! -e /.dockerenv ]] && [[ ! -e /.dockerinit ]] && exit 0

  set -xe

  # Install git (the php image doesn't have it) which is required by composer
  apt-get update -yqq
  apt-get install git -yqq
  apt-get install wget -yqq
  apt-get install zip unzip -yqq

  # Install composer
  curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

  # Install mysql driver
  # Here you can install any other extension that you need
  docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're actually installing MySQL.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Do I really need to install mysql here ? I mean, I'm using mysql docker image and I just need to override the my.cnf, what should I do ?

Comment: i think you dont need to install MySQL itself, but MySQL client.

Comment: I tried to install a mysql client : `apt-get install -y mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev` I still do not know how to override my.cnf and `/usr/local/etc/mysql/` still not exist.

Comment: Is this really the new normal for dockerized CI?  Apt-get every time?  It seems to me that there could be 1+ million new questions on StackOverflow on how to Apt-Get All the Things.  Or you could build a custom docker image that contains what you need it to contain. Is "what should I apt-get so I can connect to MySQL" really on topic for Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to easily mount the config inside of the service container using the Gitlab CI config. It is probably easier to just create a Dockerfile that extends the image that you use for testing and set the the configs you need there.

You can find an example of such a small Dockerfile here, where the author copies a config file to set the encoding to utf8:

https://hub.docker.com/r/dnhsoft/mysql-utf8/dockerfile

Or you can simply append your configs for example like this if you don't want to write a Dockerfile that copies files:

```
FROM mysql:8.0

RUN echo '[mysqld]' >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
RUN echo 'default-authentication-plugin = mysql_native_password' >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
RUN echo 'collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci' >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
RUN echo 'character-set-server = utf8mb4' >> /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf
```

Once your Dockerfile has the configs you need you can publish it to Dockerhub under your username. Then in your `gitlab-ci.yml` you can use it like this:

```
services:
    - {name: 'mydockerusername/mysql:1', alias: 'mysql'}
```

In your scripts in `gitlab-ci.yml` you can then connect to your custom database container like this:

```
script:
    - 'mysql -u gitlabci -h mysql --password="gitlabci" -e "SHOW DATABASES"'
```